# Azure SQL Database throwing error 1132 "The elastic pool has reached its storage limit" error, even if it's not full

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to execute the following (sample) batch in an Azure SQL Database inside an Elastic Pool:

```sql
drop table if exists [dbo].[InsertTest];
create table [dbo].[InsertTest] (
    [id] uniqueidentifier,
    [filler] nvarchar(max)
);

insert into [dbo].[InsertTest] ([id], [filler])
select top 1000 newid(), replicate('X', 2048)
from [sys].[objects] as [T1]
    cross join [sys].[objects] as [T2];

/* drop table if exists [dbo].[InsertTest]; */
```

But the `insert` statement fails with the error message:

```sql
Msg 1132, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The elastic pool has reached its storage limit. The storage used for the elastic pool cannot exceed (51200) MBs.
```

I tried to see if I ran out of space by running the query

```sql
select
    [type_desc]         as [file_type],
    [size] / 128        as [size_in_MB],
    [max_size] / 128    as [max_size_in_MB]
from [sys].[database_files];
```

but it seems that I still have space left.

| file_type | size_in_MB | max_size_in_MB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROWS | 320 | 256000 |
| LOG | 584 | 1048576 |
| FILESTREAM | 0 | 0 |

What can I do about it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message refers to the elastic pool so the problem might relate to another database than the current one. You can retrieve the information about the elastic pool using the following DMV query vs the Master database

```
SELECT TOP 5 avg_storage_percent / 100.0 * elastic_pool_storage_limit_mb AS ElasticPoolDataSpaceUsedInMB, * 
FROM sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats
```

Comment: I confirm my problem was related to the elastic pool. I don't have permissions to access the master database from my user, but from the Azure portal I can see the Elastic Pool storage is actually full. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same error but my elastic pool is only 50% full (almost 10 GB on 20GB). How is it possible I encounter this error while there is so much space left ? 
ElasticPoolDataSpaceUsedInMB=9666.0000000 MB, elastic_pool_storage_limit_mb=20000 (48.33 %)

Comment: OK I found it: it was due to a combinaison of a large number of databases on the same pool and an inappropriate configuration of autogrowth.